# AutoMapper behaviour changes with a POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, automapper

I have a complex object using inheritence that I map with automapper, it maps perfectly during a get request, but during a post request the ***exact same*** code doesn't map the inerited types correctly.

Let me explain. (See code below)

In the first case when I map the object during a simple get request, it maps perfectly fine and the `Parent` property of the class `A` below is of its specific type `B` or `C`.

But when the ***exact same*** mapping happens during a post, the `Parent` property of `A` is of type `A`!??

Now, the code is the same, the data model coming back from the DB is the same. (I use nhibernate - and the types are as I expect) the only difference is that it is a post request?!

Is there something I should know about AutoMapper in this case?

Class definitions (ViewModels follow the same structure):

```
public class A 
{
    public A Parent { get; set;}
}

public class B : A 
{ }

public class C : A 
{ }
```

And mapped like this:

```
CreateMap<A, AViewModel>()  
    .Include<B, BViewModel>()
    .Include<C, CViewModel>();

CreateMap<B, BViewModel>();
CreateMap<C, CViewModel>();
```

Calling map:

```
var aModel = _aManager.Get("same parameter");
var aViewModel = Mapper.Map<AViewModel>(aModel);
```

Edit #1 - This depicts the logic `in` the post Action:

```
    [Transaction] // Commits the nhibernate transaction on OnActionExecuted
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateA(OtherModelViewModel viewModel)
    { 
        var a = _aManager.Get("same parameter");

        var otherModel = Mapper.Map<OtherModel>(viewModel); 

        a.AddOtherModel(otherModel);
        _otherModelRepository.New(otherModel);

        // Eeek, writing this out I am seeing a problem here, I suspect this is where my problem would be, loading the model again from the db, after updating it in session without commiting it? I am going to change the logic and see if it fixes it.

        var aModel = _aManager.Get("same parameter");
        var aViewModel = Mapper.Map<AViewModel>(aModel);

        // return result.
    }
```

Comment: How many places do you have the `CreateMap`? Do you have them both in the Get and in Post? Or in a third place?

Comment: All my mapping will only occur once, and it would be in both post and get

Comment: Without a reproducaple code sample it is hard to answer... can you please post at least your Get method and your Post method?

Comment: It's a fairly complex framework, I wouldn't be able to post it all even if I wanted to. Is there anything specificly you would like to know or see?

Comment: It is hard to tell. AutoMapper has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC or with Nhibernate. So if you are mapping the same objects it should result in the same result unless you are doing something fishy with Automapper. Or your problem is caused by MVC or by Nhibernate itself... but again it is hard to tell. You can try to create a repro in an empty project. Usually this process helps you to find out what is problem in your original app.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is in the case of the post, I do an update to the `A` model. Which would only get Commited after the Action has executed? I will add the code above. I wonder if that puts it into a strange state of some sort?

Comment: Where is the mapping for `Mapper.Map<OtherModel>(viewModel)` defined?  Are you overwriting the `Parent` property in the `AddOtherModel` 'reverse' mapping, caching it and getting that back perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was being silly and letting the complexity get the better of me.

I use a transaction attribute, to persist the information in OnActionExecuted.

So what I was doing was > loading the model > modifing it > then loading it again and trying to map it before it had even been persisted.

I know that nHibernate really doesn't like it when you try and do things like that, so I think the in memory object graph was in a state of flux (pending commit), which was affecting the mapping.

I have change my logic to rather do an ActionRedirect after the update, which has resolved the mapping issue.

Much happier all around.